# Login using javascript remoting

Tags: community, security, javascript-remoting, login

we are trying to use AngularJS as a framework for a community site.
Problem is that the first page is accessible as a guest user.
All required remote action calls are public.
At a certain point, the calls must be made protected (via profile and apex class security)

Here we want to use some sort of login via remote actions using Site.Login
But helas, this is not working.
Session id's returned are still for guest users (but login was successful, can be seen in the login history)
Only way to let this work is use the standard login page that automagically sets session id's via cookies after refreshing the page?
no idea how to mimic this ??

Is there a way to let this work or do we have to use REST and oauth for this (hopefully not, are other limits af course)

A

Comment: We solved this by using the standard oAuth login (in a popup) and redirect to a custom callback page that will fetch via Javascript the token from the url and pass it again to the original window. Afterwards we can use this token in de visual remoting for authenticated calls.